# Webpack error since new version of Angular

Tags: angular, webpack

When I start `ng serve` I always get the error below. Peviously with Angular 11 there was not any error.

```
Generating browser application bundles...Warning: Entry point '@ngbmodule/material-carousel' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/Göbölös Márk/Desktop/Bunteto/bunteto-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/core'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-diagnostics.js:17
    compilation.errors.push(new webpack_1.WebpackError(message));
                            ^

TypeError: webpack_1.WebpackError is not a constructor
    at Object.addError (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-diagnostics.js:17:29)
    at C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\diagnostics.js:19:39
    at AngularWebpackPlugin.updateAotProgram (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:342:17)
    at C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:167:24
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:1:1), <anonymous>:24:1)     
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1030:30)
    at C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1073:29
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:1:1), <anonymous>:22:1)    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.compile (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1068:28)
    at C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:134:19
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:1:1), <anonymous>:22:1)    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at run (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:88:33)
    at C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:83:6

C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend>ng serve
⠋ Generating browser application bundles...C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-diagnostics.js:17
    compilation.errors.push(new webpack_1.WebpackError(message));
                            ^

TypeError: webpack_1.WebpackError is not a constructor
    at Object.addError (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-diagnostics.js:17:29)
    at C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\diagnostics.js:19:39
    at AngularWebpackPlugin.updateAotProgram (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:342:17)
    at C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:167:24
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:24:1)   
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1030:30)
    at C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1073:29
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:22:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.compile (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1068:28)
    at C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:134:19
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:22:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at run (C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:88:33)
    at C:\Users\Göbölös Márk\Desktop\Bunteto\bunteto-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:83:6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was: My Angular version was only 11 and not 12. I also updated all of the packages (including webpack).

Answer (score 0):

have you update Webpack to version 5? because I had this error and updating as fixing. Now i have other errors hahaha

Comment: Yes I have. The problem was that my Angular CLI was only version 11.